# Rendering page script in master layout or page in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For the past, I have been rendering the script of the page at the bottom of the each page(cshtml file), but i feel that this is a bit hard to maintain. Basically, I have only one script for each page except for the master layout.

Therefore, I would like to take alternative approach as follow, but I am not sure whether this is feasible or will have any other performance hit. Hope someone can clarify to me whether this is a good approach.

```html
<!-- In Master Layout.cshtml -->
@{
  string currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
  string currentScript = currentAction + ".js";
}

<script src= "@currentScript"></script>
```

Comment: Does every single page in your application have a corresponding JavaScript file or are there some pages that do not have a script?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you should use bundles and not call your scripts like you did, because it will improve your performance and make your scripts more compact when the site is published. You can read more here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Also good article where to put your javascript files goes here and is explained really well: http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/30/your-javascript-goes-where/

And as last to answer your question: you should minify the usage of code inside the views and this way you've build your path of the js file, if you change your project structure and move the js files into another location inside the project or change the routing your site would crash.

I hope this helps ;]